# Why is the variable set using the django 'with' tag broken into individual strings when using it in a template provided by the include tag?

Tags: django, templatetags

I am using the with tag to declare a variable my_var.  I am using my_var as a placeholder in my input box.  Only the first word of my_var is recognized as part of the variable.  How do I get the whole string to be recognized?  I have explicitly put in "placeholder='this is a test'" and all of the words show up as a place holder which leads me to believe it has something to do with using django templatetags and not the placeholder itself. [This picture shows only the word "Must" being displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1krXM.png)

```
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Must" be="" at="" least="" 4="" characters="" long="" (underscore="" period).="">
```

The above shows my_var being broken into pieces, what is wrong? Here is the code that declares my_var

```
    {% with form.username as field %}
            {% with "Must be at least 4 characters long." as my_var%}
                {% include "emp/regfield.html" %}
            {% endwith %}
    {% endwith %}
```

regfield.html looks like this

```
    <div id="div_{{ field.name }}" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_{{ field.name }}">{{ field.label }}</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{ field.name }}" placeholder={{ my_var }}>
       <div id="{{ field.name }}_error" class="error_div">
            {{ field.errors }}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing some quotation marks around your templated `{{my_var}}` - change to `"{{my_var}}"`.

Comment: Glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments to [`include`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include) like this:

```
{% include "emp/regfield.html" with field=form.username my_var="Must be at least 4 characters long." %}
```

and **get rid of** the `with` wrapper statements. Just use `include`.

Comment: Thank you, I had that as well, the problem turned out to be that I left out the quotation marks around my_var as FraserES said.